# How to organize a block of text in 8-character lines?

Tags: command-line, scripts

I'm toying around with binary code and ciphers and I've a chunk of text which I would like to reorganise in 8-character lines (those familiar with the topic will understand why). See:

```
010000100110010100100000011100110111010101110010011001
010010000001110100011011110010000001100100011100100110
100101101110011010110010000001111001011011110111010101
110010001000000100111101110110011000010110110001110100
01101001011011100110010100101110
```

I'm sure I must use `cut`, `split`, `grep`, `sort` or maybe a combination of these (and/or others), and I've made some tries with all these, but without any success.

I could easily do this manually, but this's what computers were made for, back in the World War II days :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you use bash, or some other shell that has a "-n" option for "read"

```
process to produce text |
tr -d '\n' |
while read -n 8 chars; do echo "$chars"; done
```

Answer (score 3):

Another shot:

```
tr -d '\n' <input | sed -r 's/(.{8})/\1\n/g'
```

Comment: The `sed` expression can be simplified to `s/.{8}/\0\n/g`.

Comment: if we're golfing, `s/.{8}/&\n/g` saves a character